# JSON edit in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON file like this:

```
{
   "Location":true,
   "adddress":[
      {
         "street1":" 1 58 4 16"
      },
      {
         "street2":" 3 76 57 12"
      }
      {
        "street3:":....
      }
      ...
      {
        "streetn":...
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to add 10 to the last data of street1, street2 ....so the output looks like this how to achieve this:

Expected output:

```
{
   "Location":true,
   "adddress":[
      {
         "street1":" 1 58 4 26"
      },
      {
         "sttreet2":" 3 76 57 22"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you should show us what you have tried and then we can respond with suggestions to correct/improve your code.   You should be doing your own work to learn the material either for yourself, school or work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the data is stored in the variable `json`

```
json = { "Location": True, "adddress": [ { "street1": " 1 58 4 16" }, { "sttreet2": " 3 76 57 12" }, ] }
```

As the names are different (`street1`, `sttreet2`), there are various approaches.

One, that one would be able to use for more cases, would be as follows

```
for i in range(len(json['adddress'])):
    for key in json['adddress'][i]:
        json['adddress'][i][key] = json['adddress'][i][key][:-2] + str(int(json['adddress'][i][key][-2:]) + 10)

[Out]:

{'Location': True,
 'adddress': [{'street1': ' 1 58 4 26'}, {'sttreet2': ' 3 76 57 22'}]}
```

Another one, would be more manual, and it would require one to change the respective value. For example, for `street1`, it would be as follows

```
json['adddress'][0]['street1'] = json['adddress'][0]['street1'][:-2] + str(int(json['adddress'][0]['street1'][-2:]) + 10)

[Out]:

{'Location': True,
 'adddress': [{'street1': ' 1 58 4 26'}, {'sttreet2': ' 3 76 57 12'}]}
```

For `sttreet2` it would be as follows

```
json['adddress'][1]['sttreet2'] = json['adddress'][1]['sttreet2'][:-2] + str(int(json['adddress'][1]['sttreet2'][-2:]) + 10)


[Out]:

{'Location': True,
 'adddress': [{'street1': ' 1 58 4 16'}, {'sttreet2': ' 3 76 57 22'}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `dct` is your dictionary. Then:

```
for d in dct['adddress']:
    k = next(iter(d)) # assume there's only one key in d
    vals = d[k].split()
    vals[-1] = str(int(vals[-1]) + 10)
    d[k] = ' '.join(vals)
```

The assumption I made is that each dictionary in the `dct['adddress']` list contains only one key.

Result:

```
>>> dct
{'Location': True, 'adddress': [{'street1': '1 58 4 26'}, {'sttreet2': '3 76 57 22'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```py
def get(num):
    global data
    key = data["adddress"][num].keys()[0]
    sp = [int(i) for i in data["address"][num][key].split()]
    sp[-1] += 10
    sp = [str(i) for i in sp]
    data["adddress"][num][key][num][key] = " ".join(sp)
for i in range(len(data["address"])):
    get(i)
```

This code returns:

```js
{'Location': True, 'adddress': [{'street1': '1 58 4 26'}, {'sttreet2': '3 76 57 22'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

json_data = """
{
  "Location": true,
  "adddress": [
    {
      "street1": " 1 58 4 16"
    },
    {
      "sttreet2": " 3 76 57 12"
    }
  ]
}
"""
var_add = 10
data = json.loads(json_data)
print(data["adddress"][0])
dict1 = data["adddress"][0]
for keys, value in dict1.items():
    print("Before adding: ", value) # 1 58 4 16
    lastTwo = int(value[-2:])
    # print 16
    # print(lastTwo)
    replacementStr = str(lastTwo + var_add)
    # prints 26
    # print(replacementStr)
    # replaces last two
    value = value[:-2] + replacementStr
    print("After adding: ", value) # 1 58 4 26
```

**# Output:**

```
{'street1': ' 1 58 4 16'}
Before adding:   1 58 4 16
After adding:   1 58 4 26
```

Answer (score -1):

```
new_address = []
for street in a['adddress']:
    key = list(street.keys())[0]
    value = list(street.values())[0]

    list_value = value.split(' ')
    list_value[-1] = str(int(list_value[-1]) + 10)
    new_value = ' '.join(list_value)
    new_street = {key: new_value}
    
    new_address.append(new_street)
    
a['adddress'] = new_address
```